# Not able to upgrade PostGIS - 'permission denied to set parameter "cloudsql.extension_maintenance"'

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to upgrade a Google Cloud SQL Postgres server from 9.6 to 14.

This upgrade fails with the following error

> pre-upgrade check failed: errors:{type:INVALID_EXTENSION_VERSION detail:"extension
> "postgis" needs to be upgraded to "3.1.4" before major version upgrade for database
> "optoscale""}

To upgrade the server I run

```
postgres=> alter extension postgis update to '3.1.4';
WARNING:  unpackaging raster
WARNING:  PostGIS Raster functionality has been unpackaged
HINT:  type `SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade();` to finish the upgrade. After upgrading, if you want to drop raster, run: DROP EXTENSION postgis_raster;
ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "cloudsql.extension_maintenance"
postgres=>
```

It is not clear to me where to progress further - I cannot find any documentation describing the parameter I am not able to set. I am also not able to run postgis_extensions_upgrade();

Comment: I've managed to replicate your code and managed to update PostgreSQL to `14` and PostGIS to `3.1.4`. Have you tried `sudo apt upgrade` on your cloud shell?

Comment: Thanks, but this is a Google Cloud SQL Postgres server - I do not have access to a shell, I believe. Which is also why the parameter "cloudsql.extension_maintenance" is required.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you cannot upgrade to Postgres 14 if you've PostGIS enabled in a previous version on Google Cloud. Found this here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/upgrade-major-db-version-inplace

[image: Upgrade to Postgres 14 not supported if PostGIS enabled]

Answer (score 0):

Youn should try to upgrade first to Postgres 13 and then upgrade to 14, however I would strongly suggest you to contact with [Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) if the problem persists as it is likely that you will need help from the product team to unlock this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue, looks like you can't upgrade to pg14 if you have postgis enabled in versions older than 12. I was able to upgrade from pg12 to pg14 without issues, but encountered this when upgrading pg11 to pg14.